# ProgressBar и отображение процесса работы

Tags: c#, winforms

Пока разбираюсь с async\await
Решил ещё сделать резервный вариант если с async\await ничего не получится.
Пока программа будет думать,пусть заполняется ProgressBar.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int T = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int U = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            double shag = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            int frc = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            int frc1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
            int frequency, counter;
            List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>();
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

            var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += (s, a) =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value += 5;
                if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
            for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
            {
                values.Add(reverstrans(U, frequency, T, frc, frc1,shag));
            }
            values.ForEach(x1 => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x1.Real, x1.Imaginary));   
            drawreverse(U,T, shag, frc, frc1);
            drawgraph(U, T, frc, frc1, frequency, shag);
        }
```

Как только вычисления заканчиваются то он тогда сразу зелёным.

Но планировалось чтобы он заполнялся по мере процесса вычисления,тем самым улучшая интерфейс программы.

После код я изменил

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int T = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                int U = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                double shag = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
                int frc = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
                int frc1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
                int frequency, counter;
                List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>();
                progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
                    for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
                    {
                    values.Add(reverstrans(U, frequency, T, frc, frc1,shag));
                       progressBar1.Value += frequency ;
                    }
                    values.ForEach(x1 => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x1.Real, x1.Imaginary));
       drawgraph(U, T, frc, frc1, frequency, shag);
                drawreverse(U, T, shag, frc, frc1);

           }
```

но выскочило исключение и при этом он откуда приплюсовывает к моему ProgressBar1.Maximum приплюсовывается число 28.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попытался в настройках изменить step и maximum но исключение вылетало и тех случаях и вернулся к исходным параметрам

Я посмотрел похожие вопросы и мой код совпадает частично с тем что у них.
Но выбивает исключение.

Comment: Ну все логично, у вас прогрессбар с макс допустимым значением 50, а вы пытаетесь присвоить ему значение больше этого (Value += frequency), об этом вам прямым текстом в ошибке написано.

Comment: Я задавал уже значение 5000 и всё равно он пишет что 5001 значение

Но ведь шаг нужно как-то фиксировать,движущуюся полоску.
Что нужно сделать чтобы избавится от этой проблемы?
Я не прошу код,просто куда смотреть в какое направление?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос был решён мной

После того как заполняется зелёная полоска,выходит результат и полоска во время вычислений движется.
И никаких исключений нету.

```
   progressBar1.Maximum = 5000;
                    progressBar1.Step = 1;
                    for (double fr = frc; fr <= frc1; fr += shag)
                    {
                        double resulting = (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(angularFrequency => GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, angularFrequency, T)) * Math.Cos(angularFrequency * t), 0, frc1);
                        list1.Add(fr, resulting);
                        progressBar1.PerformStep();
                    }
```